# Subscribe not executing after getting fresh access-token in Angular 10

Tags: angular, jwt, access-token, angular-http-interceptors, refresh-token

I have used `access-token` and `refresh-token` mechanism for authentication in API. when my access-token gets expired I am getting `401 Unauthorized` error in APIs. so I am calling request which returns fresh access-token using refresh-token which is working correctly. but issue is what ever code written inside `.subscribe` function is not getting re-executed.

```
getActivePlan() {
    this.myPlanExplainerActive = true;
    var route = this.router.url;
    this.ps.getUserPlan().subscribe(res => {    <========== Getting 401 Unauthorized error when accss-token expired
      var plans = res.data.plans; <===== After getting new access-token execution never goes inside.
      var activeplan = plans.find(i => i.plan.isActive == true);
      if (activeplan != undefined) {
        this.activePlanId = activeplan.plan.planId;
        if (route != "/planparser/new-pdf-upload" && this.activePlanId != '') {
          this.router.navigate(['planparser/view-plan/', this.activePlanId]);
        }
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['planparser/new-pdf-upload/']);
      }
    });
  }
```

> here when I get 401 Unauthorized error in getUserPlan() API, my interceptor get hits and fetch new access-token. but, execution never goes inside subscribe so further code not getting executed.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        let clonedRequest = request.clone();
        if (request.url.indexOf("/auth/oauth/token") == -1) {
            const auth = this.inject.get(AuthService);
            let cloned;
            if (auth.getToken()) {
                cloned = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.getToken()}`,
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                cloned = request.clone();
            }
            return next.handle(cloned).pipe(
                catchError(
                    (async (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        if (error.status === 401) {
                            return this.handle401Error(request, next);
                        } else {
                            return throwError(error);
                        }
                    })
                )
            ) as any;
        }
        else if (request.url.indexOf('/auth/oauth/token') != -1) {
            clonedRequest = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Basic ${window.btoa('ClientId' + ':' + 'secret')}`,
                    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(clonedRequest)
            .pipe(
                catchError(
                    ((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        if (error.status !== 401) {
                            this.msgs.sendMessage({ command: 'Sorry, we are unable to process your plan. Please upload your correct NDIS plan PDF again.' });
                        }
                        return throwError(error);
                    })
                )
            );
    }

    private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (!this.isRefreshingToken) {
            this.isRefreshingToken = true;
            this.tokenSubject.next(null);

            return this.authService.refreshTokenAPIcall().pipe(
                switchMap((token: any) => {
                    this.isRefreshingToken = false;
                    this.tokenSubject.next(token.access_token); <============== getting new token
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(request))
                })).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                });

        } else {
            return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
                filter(token => token != null),
                take(1),
                switchMap(jwt => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(request));
                }));
        }
    }
```

[image]